# comparing 2 html files to check for added and deleted classes

Tags: html, sharepoint

I am developing an application for SharePoint and I am referring the HTML provided by other team and
I have written some code to generate HTML content using JavaScript as I have to write the tags to fetch data from server which will be given to SharePoint server which renders my html. But there are some drastic changes made to html which now I need to re-write my JavaScript to render them properly referring to new HTML given. What would be the easy way to compare 2 HTMLs and find the new classes and deleted classes. Are there any tools which can help here?

Bottom-line is the ability to compare 2 HTML files and get the new classes, deleted classes and updated classes easily.

Comment: https://www.diffchecker.com/

Answer (score 1):

I use an application called Notepad++ its freeware and helps me a lot
There is also WinMerge you can use